# Getting results from a stored procedure, or function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble executing a stored procedure to get results back. Currently, I'd like to display results in the output window of `toad`, `eclipse`, or whatever else I'd be using. Later on, I want to access them from a program. Ignore the program part for now, unless it's essential.

I have this stored procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure pottyuserange (p_date_format in varchar2,
                                       p_start_date in varchar2,
                                       p_end_date in varchar2,
                                       p_ref_cursor out sys_refcursor)
as
begin
  open p_ref_cursor for 
    select   to_char(time_range, p_date_format) as current_date,
         lm_search,
         ao_search,
         ro_search,
         fl_search,
         total
from     (select   trunc(time_range) time_range,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'LM' then 1 else 0 end) as lm_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'AO' then 1 else 0 end) as ao_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) as ro_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'FL' then 1 else 0 end) as fl_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty in ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') then 1 else 0 end) as total           
          from     core.date_test
          where    trunc(time_range) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
          and      trunc(time_range) <= to_date(p_end_date, p_date_format)
          group by trunc(time_range))
    order by time_range asc;
  end pottyuserange;
/
```

And I'm trying to get results like this:

```
variable rc refcursor;

BEGIN
    pottyuserange('YYYY-MM-DD', '2008-10-1', '2010-10-12', :rc);
END;

print rc;
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "core.pottyuserange", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How would I correctly access this data, or turn it into a `User-Defined Function`?
\

Here's my attempt at turning it into a function:

```
create or replace function pottyuserange (p_date_format in varchar2,
                                       p_start_date in varchar2,
                                       p_end_date in varchar2)
return result_set as rc sys_refcursor;

BEGIN

OPEN result_set FOR
    select   to_char(time_range, p_date_format) as current_date,
         lm_search,
         ao_search,
         ro_search,
         fl_search,
         total
from     (select   trunc(time_range) time_range,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'LM' then 1 else 0 end) as lm_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'AO' then 1 else 0 end) as ao_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) as ro_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'FL' then 1 else 0 end) as fl_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty in ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') then 1 else 0 end) as total           
          from     core.date_test
          where    trunc(time_range) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
          and      trunc(time_range) <= to_date(p_end_date, p_date_format)
          group by trunc(time_range))
    order by time_range asc;
    return result_set;
  end pottyuserange;
/
```

The error I'm getting with the above is: `PLS-00201: identifier 'RESULT_SET' must be declared`

**EDIT**: `TIME_RANGE` is a `DATE`. `PORTA_POTTY` is a varchar2.

Comment: if you want the results in a results window, then create a user defined function rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: I updated the question. How would I translate this into a user-defined function? I've been fiddling with this, but I'm having no luck.. And I'll update the post with what I've tried.

Comment: What are the data types involved?  The error you're getting doesn't seem to make a lot of sense unless your code is doing some sort of implicit conversion.  But it's not obvious what that conversion would be.  I'm guessing that `time_range` is a `date`

Comment: @JustinCave, `time_range` is a `date` data type.

Comment: The invalid number error implies that you're doing some sort of implicit conversion.  It isn't obvious to me where in your code that is happening.  You'd have to tell us (is your table actually a view for example that is doing some sort of conversion)?

Comment: `return sys_refcursor as result_set sys_refcursor; BEGIN` would resolve the compilation error with the function.  But you'd still have the same invalid number error.

Comment: I'm not sure where the invalid number is coming from, honestly. It's a table, and not a view, that I'm querying from. I will continue to debug it.

Comment: Please add description of table. Maybe you are trying to perform trunc on varchar column? It also causes invalid number exception.

Comment: A description has been added.

Comment: @JustinCave, compiling it into a function using your correction doesn't give me a number error. It gives me this: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'pottyuserange'`. I am calling it this way: `variable rc sys_refcursor;

execute :rc:=pottyuserange('yyyy-mm-dd', '1/10/2015', '10/13/2015', :rc);

select :rc from dual`

Comment: Your function takes 3 parameters and returns a `sys_refcursor`.  You wouldn't pass `:rc` as a 4th parameter.  And there would be no point in `select :rc from dual`.  If you're using a tool like SQL*Plus that supports `print`, just `print rc`.  But when you do, I would strongly expect that you'll get the invalid number runtime error.  It would be exceptionally helpful if you could post a complete reproducible example (DDL for tables, DML to insert sample data that reproduces the problem, etc) so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: I solved the issue, I'm posting a write-up. The problem is that the start and end date input format was unexpected. After correctly converting them, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Method 1)** Create own collection type(s) and change function to return object of this type:

```
 create or replace type tp_potty as object (
  current_date varchar2(20), lm_search number(6), ao_search number(6), 
  ro_search number(6), fl_search number(6), total number(6));

create or replace type tp_potty_tbl as table of tp_potty;

create or replace function pottyuserange (p_date_format in varchar2,
                                          p_start_date in varchar2, 
                                          p_end_date in varchar2)
                                   return tp_potty_tbl is
  potty_tbl tp_potty_tbl;
begin
  select cast(multiset(
      select to_char(time_range, p_date_format) as current_date,
             lm_search, ao_search, ro_search, fl_search, total
      from  (select    trunc(time_range) time_range,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'LM' then 1 else 0 end) lm_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'AO' then 1 else 0 end) ao_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) ro_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty = 'FL' then 1 else 0 end) fl_search,
                       sum(case when porta_potty in ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') 
                                then 1 else 0 end) total
              from     date_test
              where    trunc(time_range) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
              and      trunc(time_range) <= to_date(p_end_date, p_date_format)
              group by trunc(time_range))
        order by time_range asc) as tp_potty_tbl) into potty_tbl from dual;
    return potty_tbl;
end pottyuserange;
```

Now run:

```
select * from table(pottyuserange('yyyy-mm-dd', '2015-10-10', '2015-10-15'))

CURRENT_DATE         LM_SEARCH AO_SEARCH RO_SEARCH FL_SEARCH   TOTAL
-------------------- --------- --------- --------- --------- -------
2015-10-12                   1         0         0         0       1
2015-10-13                   1         0         0         0       1
2015-10-14                   0         0         0         0       0
```

**(Method 2)** List output of cursor returned from function in PL/SQL block like here:

```
create or replace function potty2 (p_date_format in varchar2,
  p_start_date in varchar2,p_end_date in varchar2) return sys_refcursor is

  result_set sys_refcursor;

BEGIN

OPEN result_set FOR
    select   to_char(time_range, p_date_format) as current_date,
         lm_search, ao_search, ro_search, fl_search, total
from     (select   trunc(time_range) time_range,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'LM' then 1 else 0 end) as lm_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'AO' then 1 else 0 end) as ao_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) as ro_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty = 'FL' then 1 else 0 end) as fl_search,
                   sum(case when porta_potty in ('LM', 'AO', 'RO', 'FL') 
                            then 1 else 0 end) as total           
          from     date_test
          where    trunc(time_range) >= to_date(p_start_date, p_date_format)
          and      trunc(time_range) <= to_date(p_end_date, p_date_format)
          group by trunc(time_range))
    order by time_range asc;
    return result_set;
end potty2;
```

PL/SQL block:

```
declare 
  cur sys_refcursor;
  v1 varchar2(20); v2 number(6); v3 number(6); v4 number(6); v5 number(6); v6 number(6);
begin
  cur := potty2('yyyy-mm-dd', '2015-10-10', '2015-10-15');
  loop
    fetch cur into v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6;
    exit when cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(v1||' '||v2||' '||v3||' '||v4||' '||v5||' '||v6);
  end loop;
  close cur; 
end;
```

My answer is based on this article: [PL/SQL 101 : Understanding Ref Cursors](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=886365&tstart=0)

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved this a few days ago, but forgot to post an update. The issue was the date format was being parsed incorrectly. Tomorrow, I'll let you know if this works.